# Why does Bootstrap set the line-height property to 1.428571429?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

```
line-height: 1.428571429;
```

Why does [Bootstrap set `line-height`](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) to this value?

([Some themes](http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.1.1/readable/bootstrap.min.css) round it to 1.42857143.)

Comment: They also use 1.4285714286 in some versions.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

The line-height is determined by dividing the targeted line-height size by the font-size. In this example, Bootstrap is baselining their line-height off of a 14px font-size. The target line-height is 20px:

**20px ÷ 14px = 1.428571429**

When determining your line-height, you want to make sure you have ample white space between your rows. This allows for ascenders and descenders without intruding on other rows. Also having ample white space allows your eyes to develop a visual rhythm while reading.

Also keeping the line-height unitless makes it more versatile. For more information, [see Eric Meyer's post on this from February 2006.](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2006/02/08/unitless-line-heights/)

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. Looks like this question comes up on a regular basis. Maybe the Bootstrap dev code should have a quick explanatory comment.

Comment: I don't think this is a foolish question at all. I've seen this irregular `line-height` cause blurriness in IE11, which made me question it. The answer makes complete sense, but rounding the number to only a couple of decimal places would probably be prudent on Bootstrap's behalf.

Comment: Because 1.5 would have been too... pedestrian, and we developers are better than that!

Comment: @LawrenceDol It does. If your body line-height is 1.428571429, then a 20px font would have a line-height of 28.57142858, which is basically 29px.